ConnectionStrings in docker can't connect
I have a docker-compose.yml file to run a SQL Server and a C# ASP.NET Core Web API scaffolded by ABP.io:
services:
    my-api:
        container_name: my-api
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
        depends_on:
            - sqlserver
        ports:
            - "44353:44353"
    sqlserver:
        container_name: sqlserver
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
        environment:
            - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=p@ssw0rd
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
      

Here is my Dockerfile for MyApi:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0  AS base
COPY bin/Release/net8.0/publish/ app/
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]

My problem is that the API can't start because of the connection strings:
Server=sqlserver,1433;Database=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;pwd=p@ssw0rd;TrustServerCertificate=True

But I can't understand why because:

When I try to connect to the docker DB with sqlcmd or with SQL Server Management Studio from my host machine, it works fine
If I create an ubuntu docker inside the stack to ping my machine (sqlserver) by docker name, it works too
If I run sqlcmd inside the ubuntu docker with this command line /opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd -S sqlserver,1433 -U sa -P p@ssw0rd -C it works
If I run MyApi with the docker connection strings outside my docker (directly from Visual Studio), it works

I really don't see what is missing or wrong in my case.
I also cloned this repo docker-compose-demo to check if it works, and it is the case.
Is it something specific to ABP.io ? I'm clueless for now
EDIT: also, I'm not sure if it's related, but in docker logs, I see this:
2024-11-29 14:24:02 [19:24:02 ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database 'MyDatabase' on server 'sqlserver,1433'.
...
2024-11-29 14:24:02 [19:24:02 ERR] Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2024-11-29 14:24:02 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2024-11-29 14:24:02    at Microsoft.Data.Common.ADP.LocalMachineRegistryValue(String subkey, String queryvalue)
2024-11-29 14:24:02    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStaticMethods.AliasRegistryLookup(String& host, String& protocol)
2024-11-29 14:24:02    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ResolveExtendedServerName(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean aliasLookup, SqlConnectionString options)


Have you tried debugging / logging out whether the connection string is correctly set when running your API in it's docker image? Try injecting the connection string as an environment variable if not

@RasmusSøborg Yes, I just checked and the injected connection string is correct, here the ConsoleWrite in my docker console: DEBUG:      Data Source=sqlserver,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;

I'm not familiar with ABP, but the logs you just linked seems quite interesting, it tries to do a lookup: "LocalMachineRegistryValue" which is a windows specific thing, and in your docker container it will always be null.
Perhaps it can't interpret the connection string and tries to do a lookup on it?
The github you linked, has a connection string like this:
Server=sqlserver,1433;Database=MyDatabase;User=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd;TrustServerCertificate=True
Can you try with that?

I think the difference is more on this part: <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>, it could explain the LocalMachineRegistry NullException

The message "2024-11-29 14:24:02 [19:24:02 ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database 'MyDatabase' on server 'sqlserver,1433'" should only be in your logs when the database MyDatabase did not exist, so maybe only 1 time before you created that database ?

@Luuk, unfortunately not, my first try was to do the same after executing the DbMigrator project and the result was the same, but it seems to work with Aspire, very weird

I ran into this issue today. I found that my problem was the following in the csproj
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
